# How to use drivers in order to allow a rotation of an object in the x axis to be mirrored as a rotation in the y axis?

Tags: mesh, drivers, mathematics

Is there anyway to make an object rotate for the same value in the z axis when the y axis rotation is changed. It is to rotate the door as attached, as it needs to rotate at an angle.[image: Door needs to rotate at an angle or else it goes into the hull mesh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to determine the origin and axis of rotation with a parent Empty, and rotate the parent?

[image]

Comment: or put in the rarely used axis angle rotation mode.

Comment: .. @batFINGER  true. ... just thinking, though, ... for the complex motion of  an aeroplane hatch, the parent may need to translate, and maybe, itself, rotate about an origin other than its own..

Comment: For sure.,  Re hatch, tracking on path(s)  could be the go, just a tick I'll go out the back and check the hatch on the _Lear_

Comment: @batFINGER _go out the back_? Such an _effort_! Can't you just summon your ground-crew?

Comment: used this on something  else but helpful nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

Hover on the y rot value, right click and choose "copy as new driver", then hover on the z rot value and right click "paste driver".

Then you can choose "edit driver" to change the math if needed.

Remember that thoose values ar local, and it's a good habit to apply (Ctrl A) rot and scale to any object before starting animations and simulations.